# iOS application crash while show popover

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uipopovercontroller

In application rootviewController allocated like

```
navigationContr = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginViewController];
loginViewController = nil;
self.window.rootViewController = _navigationViewController;
```

After login I push MainViewController like this

```
MainViewController * mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
mainViewController.isNavigateFromLogin  = YES;
/** push the Main screen*/
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mainViewController animated:NO];
mainViewController = nil;
```

On MainViewController I am adding view of another viewController like this

```
gridViewControllerObj = [[GridViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"GridViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:gridViewControllerObj.view];
```

GridViewController added on button, on button click we showed popover. Code below
Memory allocated to "operationsViewController"

```
self.optionsPopOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:operationsViewController];
[_orderOptionsPopOver presentPopoverFromRect:frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown|UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:NO];
```

This is flow of show popover,if run app on device I see warning print on console. After time out I go back to first view

**Issue 1:**

> BusinessApplication[8321] : Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged .
>    For this case app work but not crash

To fix this warning ,I searched on forum for above warning, there are solution suggested like

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate* )[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIView *rootView = appDelegate.window.rootViewController.view;
```

After providing rootview to popover above warning goes of

```
[_orderOptionsPopOver presentPopoverFromRect:frame inView:rootView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown|UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:NO];
```

**Issue 2:**
After apply of above solution on time out application get crashed.

I got following crash log

```
BusinessApplication[511] <Warning>: Warning: sync SCNetworkReachability (by-name) query on main thread
mstreamd[513] <Notice>: (Note ) PS: MSSubscriber - 1456278278 Finished retrieving assets. Checking for errors on 0 assets...
BusinessApplication[511] <Warning>: Warning: sync SCNetworkReachability (by-name) query on main thread
BusinessApplication[511] <Warning>: Warning: sync SCNetworkReachability (by-name) query on main thread
BusinessApplication[511] <Warning>: Stack Trace: uncaughtExceptionHandler 
     (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x25f0fd7f <redacted> + 150
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x33aefc77 objc_exception_throw + 38
        2   UIKit                               0x29696533 <redacted> + 2918
        3   UIKit                               0x2969809b <redacted> + 94
        4   UIKit                               0x293c11a1 <redacted> + 72
        5   UIKit                               0x29697fcf <redacted> + 198
        6   UIKit                               0x2949c199 <redacted> + 168
        7   UIKit                               0x294c5741 <redacted> + 116
        8   UIKit                               0x294c4721 <redacted> + 120
        9   UIKit                               0x294037a3 <redacted> + 66
        10  Foundation                          0x26c16dc9 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 468
        11  CoreFoundation                      0x25ed6517 <redacted> + 14
        12  CoreFoundation                      0x25ed6099 <redacted> + 656
        13  CoreFoundation                      0x25ed4303 <redacted> + 1418
        14  CoreFoundation                      0x25e21981 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
        15  CoreFoundation                      0x25e21793 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
        16  GraphicsServices                    0x2d1b1051 GSEventRunModal + 136
        17  UIKit                               0x29413981 UIApplicationMain + 1440
        18  BusinessApplication                 0x003ddc17 main + 170
        19  libdyld.dylib                       0x3408baaf <redacted> + 2
    )
BusinessApplication[511] <Warning>: CRASH: Application tried to present modally an active controller <MainViewController: 0x16a78b30>.
BusinessApplication[511] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <MainViewController: 0x16a78b30>.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x25f0fd67 0x33aefc77 0x29696533 0x2969809b 0x293c11a1 0x29697fcf 0x2949c199 0x294c5741 0x294c4721 0x294037a3 0x26c16dc9 0x25ed6517 0x25ed6099 0x25ed4303 0x25e21981 0x25e21793 0x2d1b1051 0x29413981 0x3ddc17 0x3408baaf)
ReportCrash[516] <Error>: task_set_exception_ports(B07, 400, D03, 0, 0) failed with error (4: (os/kern) invalid argument)
ReportCrash[516] <Notice>: ReportCrash acting against PID 511
ReportCrash[516] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process BusinessApplication[511]
mediaserverd[36] <Notice>: '' com.xp.businessApp(pid = 511) setting DiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None, currentDiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.xp.businessApp[0x2b0f][511]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Abort trap: 6
<Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.xp.businessApp[0x2b0f]' crashed.
assertiond[54] <Warning>: pid_suspend failed for <BKNewProcess: 0x16d885d0; com.xp.businessApp; pid: 511>: Unknown error: -1, Unknown error: -1
assertiond[54] <Warning>: Could not set priority of <BKNewProcess: 0x16d885d0; com.xp.businessApp; pid: 511> to 2, priority: No such process
assertiond[54] <Warning>: Could not set priority of <BKNewProcess: 0x16d885d0; com.xp.businessApp; pid: 511> to 4096, priority: No such process
UserEventAgent[17] <Warning>: id=com.xp.businessApp pid=511, state=0
ReportCrash[516] <Notice>: Saved report to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/BusinessApplication_2015-03-14-171423_IPad.ips
locationd[60] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
locationd[60] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
mstreamd[513] <Notice>: (Note ) mstreamd: Not monitoring for external power.
mstreamd[513] <Notice>: (Note ) PS: Media stream daemon stopping.
mstreamd[513] <Notice>: (Note ) AS: <MSIOSAlbumSharingDaemon: 0x14e30790>: Shared Streams daemon has shut down.
mstreamd[513] <Notice>: (Warn ) mstreamd: mstreamd shutting down.
<Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
<Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
locationd[60] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
locationd[60] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
```

Comment: Why are you setting things to nil? You're deallocating the object by assigning nil to it. When you pass an object as an argument, that doesn't mean that the object is duplicated.

Comment: @Schemetrical i assign object to nil for deallocate object, I think this is not issue. Did you get my issue related to popover warning

Answer (score 0):

The problem in what you're doing is that you've created a pitfall chain for yourself.

You create a couple of controllers, and present them, but after you present them, you deallocate them. You can't present something you deallocate. This leads to the first issue, trying to present another controller when your current controller is nil.

Next, you take the error message and search for a solution out of context. That is not a solution to your problem and obviously it will lead to a crash if you try and use it.

The first thing you need to do is to remove the nil assign. I don't know why you're doing it and I'm certain its causing many problems.

When you have `*a = *b`, and `*c = *a`, if you set `c = nil`, all of the rest of the variables will be nil as well because its how pointers work. I'm happy to help you some more if you don't mind somebody looking at your code, but I can't do much if problematic calls are still in there.